# Instantiating Class with Implicit Field

Tags: scala, implicit

Given this class with an `implicit` Int.

```
scala> class Foo(implicit val x: Int) { 
     |   def getX = x
     | }
defined class Foo
```

I can create one explicitly via:

```
scala> val f = new Foo()(1)
f: Foo = Foo@21aba4f3
```

But I can't with:

```
scala> val f = new Foo(100)
<console>:18: error: too many arguments for constructor Foo: ()(implicit x: Int)Foo
       val f = new Foo(100)
```

What's going on with the `()` argument?

Answer (score 5):

A class with only the implicit parameter list is syntactic sugar for a class with two parameter lists, the first one of which is empty.

Given

```
class Foo(implicit val x: Int)
```

here's the expanded representation as printed in the REPL with the `-Xprint:type` flag

```
class Foo extends scala.AnyRef {
  <paramaccessor> private[this] val x: Int = _;
  implicit <stable> <accessor> <paramaccessor> def x: Int = Foo.this.x;
  def <init>()(implicit x: Int): Foo = {
    Foo.super.<init>();
    ()
  }
}
```

So you can either not provide any parameter list

```
implicit val x = 42 
val foo = new Foo
```

or provide both

```
val foo = new Foo()(42)
```